# Using a directory structure for robot framework testing

Tags: testing, robotframework

I want to run tests in Robot Framework.

I would also like the following kind of directory structure for the robot framework tests:

- Root directory

  - Libraries

    - Library.py
  - Resource Files

    - Resource.txt
  - Tests

    - test_1.txt
    - test_2.txt

Or something along those lines. However, I do not know how to write my tests so they can access my library and resource files. For example, how to import Libraries\Library.py from Tests\test_1.txt.

What would be the best way to approach this?
Is there a syntax for acessing files in the parent directory?
Should I import the resource and library files in every test file, or is there a way to do it only once?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Using relative imports

Robot supports relative imports. You can use `..` to represent the parent of a directory. In your example you would do it this way:

```
*** Settings ***
| Resource | ../Resource Files/Resource.txt
| Library  | ../Libraries/Library.py
```

### Defining the root in a variable

You can use variables in your settings table, so you could define a variable that points to the root of your repository. You would use this variable for all of your imports. For example:

```
*** Settings ***
| Resource | ${ROOT}/Resource Files/Resource.txt
| Library  | ${ROOT}/Libraries/Library.py
```

You can set this variable on the command line with the `--variable` option:

```
$ pybot --variable ROOT /path/to/root tests
```

Comment: Thank you, this will come in handy.

Answer (score 13):

Robot automatically defines an `${EXECDIR}` variable that we're using in place of `${ROOT}` from Bryan's answer.

Pros:

- System-independent

Cons:

- May depend on how you invoke PyBot (working dir in command prompt, or which folder you open in RIDE)

Comment: EXECDIR was exactly what I needed!